# Reducing iterations on nested list loops

Tags: java, json, collections, java-8, java-stream

Need help in minimizing loop iterations.

I have 2 different List objects

```java
public class Material {
    private String mtrlId;
    private String uomId;
    private String sapEndDate;
}
```

```java
public class UnitPrice {
    private String unitPrice;
    private String uomId;
}
```

I will get a request as two lists of the above objects.

```
List<Material> list1 = Arrays.asList(
        new Material("1011", "10054700", "2023-04-29"));
                    
List<UnitPrice> list2 = Arrays.asList(
        new UnitPrice("1.59", "10054700"));
```

Now, I want to add `unitPrice=1.59` from `list2` to be added to `list1` based on `uomId`.

I have tried following so far, please help me in achieving same. Once I get in the original list, I will add it to JSONArray to process further.

As this is a nested loop, am getting 6 iterations and the result is repetitive.

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for (Material material : list1) {
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
    array.put(
        obj1.put("mtrlId", material.getMtrlId())
            .put("mtrlUomId", material.getUomId())
            .put("sapEndDate", material.getSapEndDate()));
                
    for (UnitPrice unit : list2) {
        if (unit.getUomId().equals(material.getUomId())) {
            array.put(obj1.put("unitPrice", unit.getUnitPrice()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does not work? It seems okay on a first glance. Is the output incorrect or is this a question of optimization?

Comment: Just put an `exit` inside the nested loop `if...` helps a lot. If both lists are very large, suggest you to sort the unitPrice list first and then use quick search.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a map `Map<String, Material>` from `List<Material>` with a key as the `uomId` that identifies the `Material`. This structure very efficient for a look-up for the correct `Material` by `uomId`.

```java
final Map<String, UnitPrice> map = list2.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                UnitPrice::getUomId,      // uomId as a key
                Function.identity()));    // the whole object itself as a value
```

Now you are ready to do fill in the JSON structure in a single loop. Assuming your goal is the following output...

```json
[
  {
    "unitPrice": "1.59",
    "mtrlUomId": "10054700",
    "sapEndDate": "2022-10-03T14:39:44.526605",
    "mtrlId": "1011"
  }
]
```

... the code looks like this ...

```java
final JSONArray array = new JSONArray();              // outer array
for (Material material: list1) {                      // for each Material
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();               // ... create a JSON object
    String unitPrice = map.get(material.getUomId())   // ... look-up by uomId
                          .getUnitPrice();            // ...... and get the unitPrice

    obj1.put("mtrlId", material.getMtrlId())          // ... add mtrlId 
        .put("mtrlUomId", material.getUomId())        // ... add uomId   
        .put("sapEndDate", material.getSapEndDate())  // ... add sapEndDate 
        .put("unitPrice", unitPrice);                 // ... add unitPrice from the map

    array.put(obj1);                                  // ... add JSON object into JSON array
}
```

... and print it out as a beautified JSON with indentation:

```java
System.out.println(array.toString(2));
```

Remember this solution assumes there is always exactly one `Material` identified by `uomId`.

Comment: Yes . Got it . Thank you so much for this solution . It helps a lot . Yes There are chances of multiple materials for same uomId . I figured that out .